# Is it possible to host Drupal on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, drupal

As Drupal is written in Python, one could think it would be possible to host a site on Google App Engine?

Thank you, Drupal is written in PHP - any suggestion for Content Management System on GAE.

Regards
Christian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that Google has launched PHP support for App Engine, yes it is possible. See http://blog.boombatower.com/drupal-google-app-engine for details.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) which is written Python, not Drupal which is written in PHP. See [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel) for running Django on Google Apps Engine.